# How do i store the exitcode of a remote sshpass command into a variable in my locally running script

Tags: bash, ssh, variable, exit-status

How do I write the exitcode of a remote sshpass command into a variable in my local script for further use?

I am using sshpass in order to remotely execute a command. I know that certificate based authentication is better, but it's not my system and I can not set up cert based authentication.

My problem is that I am not able to catch the exit code of the remote command into my variable $errm.

My command looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p $pass ssh -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no -t $user@$Hostip 'touch /does/not/exist.txt &>/dev/null errm=$?'

echo $errm
```

`echo $errm` does not show anything no matter if I give it a true path or one which /does/not/exist.txt. However, the file is created remotely if I provide a valid path, so everything sshpass related works but I just can't catch the exit code.

However, if I do it this way at least my script shows me the exit code of the remote command as it is running, but as I mentioned, I am not able to catch it in a variable for further use in the same script

```
sshpass -p $pass ssh -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no -t $user@$Hostip 'touch /does/not/exist.txt &>/dev/null && echo $? || echo $?'
```

I think the problem has something to do with the error code being thrown on the remote system while my script runs locally!?

Comment: Please delete [your SO copy of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526458/how-di-i-write-the-exitcode-of-a-remote-sshpass-command-into-a-variable-for-furt); thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself:

```
sshpass -p $passvar ssh -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no -t $uservar@$ItemHostIp 'touch /does/not/exist.txt &>/dev/null'; errm=$?
```